# Протироположность :first-child

Tags: css

Есть ли какая-то противоположность `:first-child`, чтобы выделить вместо первого, последний элемент?

Для примера, вот HTML:

```html
<span>123</span>
<span>456</span>
<span>789</span>
```

В этом HTML коде нужно выбрать последний элемент, также есть условие `span`-ов есть неопределённое кол-во, но нам нужно выделить именно последний элемент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Последний элемент можно выделить используя `:nth-last-child`

Для примера вот CSS:

```css
span:nth-last-child(1) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Подробней вы можете ознакомиться на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child) или [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-last-child.asp)

---

Дополнение от **teran**:

Пример с `:last-child` CSS:

```css
span:last-child {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Подробней на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) или [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp)

Comment: как ни странно, достаточно просто `:last-child`

Comment: Тоже как вариант, сейчас же добавлю в ответ.